# Переключение функций

Tags: javascript

Господа помогите пожалуйста, есть функция которая по событию ховер проверяет наличие класса и если есть определенный класс она выводит одну информацию если класс другой то другую, 
Могу ли я сделать чтобы по наведению на определенный объект работала функция ховер но поклику на тот же объект функция ховер перестала работать и выполнялся алгоритм по событию клик , после повторного нажатия включалась опять функция ховер .

Comment: В JavaScript нет события ховер, есть mouseenter|mouseleave|mousemove.
А так почему нет, убирайте событие и заново цепляйте.

Comment: @Alex Krass, в js есть onmouseover и onmouseout, на основе которых можно построить полноценный ховер =)

Comment: вот проще будет показать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

через глобальную переменную, например:

```
var clicked = false; //ваша переменная объявленная в самом начале

function onhover(){
 if (clicked) {
     alert("clicked"); //hover выключен
 } else {
     alert('hover');// hover включен
 }

function clicked(){
    clicked = ! clicked; //включаем/выключаем hover
}
```

код схематичный, лишь для примера

p.s.: проще всего событие hover реализуется в jquery:

```
$(элемент).hover(function() {
  //указатель над элементом
}, function() {
  //указатель покинул элемент
});
```

Comment: можно использовать dataset объекта, но мне кажется это мутарно

Answer (score 1):

```
$(el).on("click", function(){
  $(this).unbind("mouseenter hover");
});
```